How to disable days of the week by periods?
I'm currently trying to add a date picker (Boostrap datepicker) and disable certain days of the week, like Mondays, to prevent reservations on those days when the office is closed. I found the daysOfWeekDisabled parameter, and it works perfectly, but not specifically for this purpose:
$('#date_return').datepicker({
    language: "es",
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    maxView: 1,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: $scope.daysClosedInLocationOfReturn
});

This setup works as expected, but now I need to make it apply to specific periods. For example, from 12/31/2024 to 12/30/2025, and then another period from 12/31/2025 to 12/30/2026. Additionally, the days might change depending on the period.
I also searched online and found what I hoped would solve my problem:
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
    return date.day() === 0 || date.day() === 6;
}

With this function, I thought I could add more conditions to check additional criteria, like specific years or other conditions. However, it didn’t work as expected—it neither disabled the days of the week nor showed any error message. Is there any way I can block specific days within certain periods?

How about using disabledDates? Assuming that that is the manual for data picker you're using.

@KIKOSoftware isn't eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker another datetimepicker?

What library do you use? Do you have a link to the documentation? Is it this old school library that was last updated in 2014 and shouldn't be used any more? https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

I've been using these docs, and I think the beforeShowDay option is working for my needs. It checks each day shown in the calendar, so it might be a bit slow, but it should do the job.

Ah, you edited your question to add the correct link to the date-picker. I got the link to the manual from the bootstrap-datetimepicker tag in your question. Clearly you're not using that one.

Oh sorry, I just changed the tag, Thanks for telling me!

Not sure if you can hide specific periods with your current date picker.
However you can do so with Bootstrap Datepicker
With that you can use beforeShownDay option to implement your custom logic.
Example:
$('#date_return').datepicker({
   language: "es",
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
   autoclose: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var day = date.getDay(); // 0 (Sunday) ... 6 (Saturday)

       // The periods with the days to disable
       var periods = [
           {
               start: new Date(2024, 11, 31),
               end: new Date(2025, 11, 30),
               daysToDisable: [1] // Mondays
           },
           {
               start: new Date(2025, 11, 31),
               end: new Date(2026, 11, 30),
               daysToDisable: [2, 3] // Tuesdays and Wednesdays
           }
       ];

       for (var i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
           var period = periods[i];
           if (date >= period.start && date <= period.end) {
               if (period.daysToDisable.includes(day)) {
                   return false; // Disable this specific date
               }
           }
       }
       return true; // Enable all other dates
   }
});



I've tried using it but it does not seem to work, I've change the periods to 2024, 10, 1 | 2024, 10, 30 and 2024, 11, 1 | 2024, 11, 30 but it does not disable the days, should I add something else?

I just read your last comment under the question's comment thread.  Was my answer helpful? Because if it wasn't I can delete it.

It seems to work pretty well! I was checking it in a wrong case. My fault! Let me check that it works perfectly and marked as a solution!
